# Configuring multiple Nginx load balancers for failover

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, http, failover

I am attempting to set up a test Nginx load balanced environment. So far I have sucessfully configured a load balancer `nginx-balancer1` and 3 servers to serve webpages `nginx1, nginx2 & nginx3`.

`nginx-balancer1` serves pages from `nginx1, nginx2 or nginx3` depending on `weight` assigned to the server.

What I need to figure out now is how I can setup failover for the `nginx-balancer1` as if it is knocked offline, the webpage will go offline :(

If anyone has any information or can point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We use keepalived and VRRP to share a virtual IP between our HAProxy load balancers.

This approach requires that both balancers are on the same subnet.

Load balancers in divergent datacenters / networks will likely have to leverage a solution like DNS failover.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I am going to utilise a service like OVH's failover IP.